# Compile for the App Store using FlashDevelop

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I test my iOS app on device in FlashDevelop using the PackageApp.bat file.

It is the fast interpreter version.

I have a .p12 file for development and the .mobileprovision.

What do I need to publish for the app store?

Do I need a different p12 file? A different mobileprovision file?

Mirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a distribution certificate (I guess in a p12 file) and an AppStore distribution provisioning profile.